# Azure samples - WebApp-WSFederation-DotNet

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

The sample app can be found here --> https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation.

**The application is using Microsoft.Owin and this is what I am expecting:**

1. Users navigate to your application.
2. Your application redirects anonymous users to authenticate at Azure AD, sending a WS-Federation protocol request that indicates the application URI for the realm parameter. The URI should match the App ID URI shown in the single sign-on settings.
3. The request is sent to your tenant WS-Federation endpoint, for example: https://login.windows.net/solexpaad.onmicrosoft.com/wsfed
4. The user is presented with a login page, unless he or she already has a valid cookie for the Azure AD tenant.
5. When authenticated, a SAML token is returned in the HTTP POST to the application URL with a WS-Federation response. The URL to use is specified in the single sign-on settings as the Reply URL.
6. The application processes this response, verifies the token is signed by a trusted issuer (Azure AD), and confirms that the token is still valid.

**My Question:**

After the authentication a SAML token is returned via the HTTP POST. How can I view the SAML response? Currently when I view the HttpContext after POST there is nothing in it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs, you should be able to get access to the token.
I've added the SecurityTokenReceived Func:

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
    new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Wtrealm = realm,
        MetadataAddress = metadata,
        Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenReceived = context =>
                {
                    // Get the token
                    var token = context.ProtocolMessage.GetToken();
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks!! I found it in the ProtocolMessage. I assume RequestSecurityTokenResponse is valid SAML?

Comment: @Villain, look at the explanation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.4.1/html/Web_Services_Security_Guide/files/WsTrust-Demo-Messages.html